# Enabling only one checkbox in a row in Access Multiple Item Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a multiple item form, where most of the checkboxes are disabled unless the user checks the box before it.

Currently I'm using:

```
If Me.Field1 Then
    Me.chxField2.Enabled = True
Else
    Me.chxField2.Enabled = False
End If
```

But if I check the box, it enables the Field2 checkbox for all of them, I only want it to enable the checkbox for one particular row.

[image]
[image]

Is this possible to do? If it isn't, that's ok but I just had to ask.

**Edit**: Thanks to Erik I did this in the BeforeUpdate like he described, and it gives the effect I wanted:

```
Private Sub chxField2_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Cancel = Not Field1
    chxField2.Undo
End Sub
```

Comment: For the record (pun not intended), that condition could be simplified to `Me.chxField2.Enabled = Me.Field1`

Comment: @Mat'sMug oh nice! I'll make sure to use it like that in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not (as far as I know).

On a continuous form, there's actually only one instance of each control. This means that you can't have one of those Field2 checkboxes enabled, and another disabled.

Things you can do:

Use the Checkbox_BeforeUpdate event to check if Field1 is checkded. If it isn't checked, then rollback the change:

```
Private Sub Field2_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Cancel = Not Field1
End Sub
```

Also, if you weren't using a checkbox, you would be able to use conditional formatting to give the control a "disabled look". Unfortunatlely, conditional formatting doesn't apply to checkboxes.

Comment: Have a look at the approach suggested in this thread: [Disable Check Box Based on Other Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606976/disable-check-box-based-on-other-values)